estoy trabajando con una aplicación web en genexus 18. al intentar abrir un objeto dashboard da el sifgiente error: Error starting Kestrel
inicié a trabajar con una aplicación web en genexus 18. al intentar abrir un objeto dashboard da el sifgiente error: Error starting Kestrel
cuál puede ser la solución?
(en genexus 17 nunca me dió ese error)

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Nestor, encontraste la solucion? tengo el mismo problema! jaja

¿Con qué generador? A nivel generador, ¿qué valor tienes en la propiedad "Web Server"?

Hola! en la propiedead  web server: Internet Information Server

hola, todavía sigo buscando solución

En una maquina no puedo arreglarlo pero en las otras si, y lo hice instalando esto https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-8.0.404-windows-x64-installer capaz te sirve

excelente, ya lo instalé y quedó funcionando todo ok. Muchas gracias!

Tiene instalado net core 8?
El IDE de gx lo necesita para mostrar los objetos dashboard y queryviewer.
Lo menciona en los requerimientos
https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/wiki?30900,GeneXus+18+hardware+and+software+requirements

Muchas gracias!
